# Parsing Values + removing garbage

Tags: c#, parsing

just started with a new project, and i need to extract the first value from a bunch of sequences like these

```
710:0:0:0:60:recym.wav
0:0:0:60:kick-1.wav
0:0:0:60:cymbal.wav
0:0:0:0:
1094:0:0:0:0:
1383:0:0:0:0:
1575:0:0:0:0:
1863:0:0:0:0:
2056:0:0:0:0:
2152:0:0:0:0:
```

i just need the first value of every row so i would want an output like 710, 0, 0, 0, 1094, 1383, 1575, 1863, 2056, 2152

first i tried to parse like this 
`int value = int.Parse(line);` 
which obviusly didn't work but i dont know how to remove the last bit. thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like your lines are delimeted by `:`.  If this is always the case, split on `:`, then grab the first one and try to get an `int` out of it:

```
 foreach(var line  in lines)
 {
    var first = line.Split(':').FirstOrDefault();
    if(int.TryParse(first, out var number))
    {
        //do something with valid number
    }
 }
```